# Easy way to run python file for client

Tags: python, automation

I made a python program that automates an excel organization process for a family member that took them a long time to do manually and the program seems to work. The issue is my family member wants to be able to easily run the program without having to go into the command line and actually run the file. Is there a way that they could run the program just by clicking something on their desktop or something easy like that? I don't think I can use task scheduler because the file needs to be input by the user and the user won't need to run the program at some specific time. Let me know if there is any way to make this as easy as possible for my family member.

Comment: Just create a shortcut to `python scriptname.py`. Maybe change your script so it prompts the user to select the file.

Comment: Would this run the file when clicking the shortcut? @GordonAitchJay

Comment: I don't know. Post your code.